# Unable to store data using flask as backend and kivy as frontend

Tags: python, flask, kivy, localhost, backend

```
# This is app.py (Flask backend)

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/images/'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['image']
    if file:
        filename = file.filename
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> app.py, main.py & index.html are used

```
# main.py (kivy frontend)

import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView

class RootLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.file_chooser = FileChooserIconView()
        self.file_chooser.bind(selection=self.on_file_selection)

        self.add_widget(self.file_chooser)

        self.image_display = Image()
        self.add_widget(self.image_display)

        self.upload_button = Button(text='Upload Image')
        self.upload_button.bind(on_release=self.upload_image)
        self.add_widget(self.upload_button)

    def on_file_selection(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            self.image_display.source = value[0]

    def upload_image(self, *args):
        if self.image_display.source:
            filename = os.path.basename(self.image_display.source)
            os.system(f'curl -F "image=@{self.image_display.source}" http://localhost:5000/upload')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

> I'm unable to upload the file to store in the server (for now in the local disk)

```
# This is index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Uploader</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
        <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Can anyone help me with flask backend with kivy frontend. I'm working on kivy app I want to store and update data on my kivy apk with the help of back end like uploading Profile Picture, downloading images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using os command for HTTP request?
I think that's the main problem.
use request library instead:

```
pip install requests
```

import requests

```
def upload_image(self, *args):
    if self.image_display.source:
        filename = os.path.basename(self.image_display.source)
        with open(self.image_display.source, 'rb') as f:
            files = {'image': (filename, f)}
            requests.post('Your Endpoint', files=files)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its running this way but the problem of storing the file is yet not solved.